# Heapsort - building heap

Tags: sorting, build, heap

We have to know how to use a heap sort. I can't understand a one thing: when we build a heap, why the size used in loop is divided by 2 (declared as a counter "i")? Below is shown the code. I would be so grateful if anyone would explain it to me.

```
// heap

void heapify (int tab[], int o, int heapsize)
{
    int l = 2 * o + 1;
    int r = l + 1;
    int largest;

    if (l <= heapsize && tab[o] > tab[l])
        largest = l;
    else
        largest = o;

    if (r <= heapsize && tab[largest] > tab[r])
        largest = r;

    if (largest != o)
    {
        swap(tab[o], tab[largest]);
        heapify(tab, largest, heapsize);
    }
}

void build_heap(int tab[], int heapsize)
{
    for (int i = heapsize/2; i >= 0; i--)
        heapify(tab, i, heapsize);
}

void heap_sort(int tab[], int size)
{
    int heapsize = size;
    build_heap(tab, heapsize);

    do{
        swap(tab[0], tab[heapsize]);
        heapify(tab, 0, heapsize - 1);
        heapsize--;
    } while (heapsize > 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean the line

```
for (int i = heapsize/2; i >= 0; i--)
```

Well, what's happening is like this. But first, here's a tip for heaps. You have to constantly switch between the two ways to think about a heap: a contiguous array and a tree.

So if you look at `heapify`, you can see in the array representation that for index `i`, the code considers `l` and `r` which are `2 * i` and `2 * i +`. In the tree representation, those are the left and right children.

Now in the heap representation, what is `heapsize / 2`? It is the part of the penultimate row that actually has children. These children will be considered by the `heapify` function (we just saw that). There's no point starting to the right of that, since there just aren't children to compare.

Comment: Indeed, I haven't nodiced we work of the last part of nodes contain childs. But what about nodes staying above of those? How set we a root, for example, if we don't work of the highest part of tree?

Comment: @edit: it seems me I understand. So when we will decrement a counter, we will reach to root step by step (other words: we just build a heap from the end?)?

Comment: Thank you man :). So: we use heapify (only heapify, not including a build_heap) to set the father of the three elements? (and if we make any change, the function use a recursion, because we could disrupt the balance of the heap).

Comment: Basically yes. To be precise, heapify is called on the parent on the three. It restores order between these three elements. The reason that it is called backward (in the array rep.) is that the bottom part of the tree is organized, and we don't want to ruin it. Instead, we just go up in the tree (which is left in the array), and keep on fixing until we're done.

Comment: Ok. So: comparing a heap to a sorted list basic on heap, in a sorted list the children must be sorted, contrast to heap. Isn't it? :)